# Why check $_GET twice?

Tags: php, get, isset

I'm learning PHP and I hoping you can explain why the author of a shopping cart tutorial has done this in a call to add a product to a cart.

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add")
```

The site checks that `$_GET[action]` is set and that `$_GET[action]` is equal to 'add' before processing but isn't this functionally equivalent to just:

```
if($_GET['action']=="add")
```

Because if the value is 'add' it **has** to be set, and if it's not set it can't possibly be 'add' right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why not find it out yourself? Make sure you have error reporting turned on: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Then call the url, once with the query string, e.g. `xy.php?action=add` and once without it: `xy.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Attempting to access an array key which has not been defined is the same as accessing any other undefined variable: an E_NOTICE-level error message will be issued, and the result will be NULL.

Checking `isset` is a good defensive measure to keep your logs from being spammed by these (useless) messages.

Comment: I wouldn't call them useless - if the code would be `if($_GET['action']==0)` the message would indicate a real (potential) problem.

Comment: @fvu Perhaps that wasn't the greatest wording. In this case, they don't add any useful info - you meant to check if `GET['add']`. You know exactly what you're doing and why it fails. It's not as though you got a surprising user input you weren't prepared for.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. The result of the second comparision failing would be an error, while the first comparison is just null which would be better if it's not set to 'add'.

Answer (score 5):

No, thats not the same
Let me explaint 
1. isset check either key is set in array
2. Double equals check the simple comparison

Answer (score 1):

No, not the same. Consider a querystring such as `?action=add&product=banana` - in this case the statement `if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add")` would be valid and the script could then process whatever was required once that condition was deemed satisfied. If you omit the `action` parameter and use a querystring such as `?product=banana&colour=red` the if statement would throw an error warning about undefined indexes.

The `isset` tests that the named variable is available in the `$_GET` array - alternatively you could use `if( array_key_exists('action',$_GET) && $_GET['action']=='add' ){` etc

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary because firstly it will check whether it is set `$_GET['action']` means it is not null and then it checks it has to be value `add` then perform certain code, not if value is `edit` or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been given, but I'd like to add that in a condition that uses *&&* the right hand expression won't get executed if the left expression already returned false. 
So the following would still return a Warning-Notice if Error-Reporting is set accordingly:

```
if($_GET['action']=="add" && isset($_GET['action']))
```

You have to check isset() first, as it was done in your code example.

More examples on the way PHP handles logical operators in conditions:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php#example-139